# How can you pass a sql query through ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I have sql query I need pass through to an ajax file.

```
$qry = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT * FROM products");
```

I have contained the variable in html such as:

```
<input type="button" data-qry="'.$qry.'" id="button" value="click">
```

I use the ajax jquery code below to pass it through:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    array = $(this).attr('data-qry');
    $.ajax({        
        type    : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        url     : 'ajax.php',
        data    : 'qry='+qry,
        success : function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I want to be able to open ajax.php and perform

```
$qry = $_POST['qry'];
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry);
```

Of course this is not working. How can I pass the query through, does it need to be done through JSON some how?

Comment: Allowing the *user* to specify the SQL query that you're executing sounds like a *very dangerous idea*.  I hope you trust your users.

Comment: What other ways could this be done?

Comment: That entirely depends on what it is that you want to do.  If you want your users to write their own SQL queries then this approach is fine once it works.  But it's really not clear *why* you want to allow that.  It's fine if your users can be trusted, but still worth mentioning just in case anybody else comes across this question.

Comment: If a malicious user found the page that AJAX script is sending to they could input `delete from users` (assuming you have a users table) and then all your users are deleted; amongst other things (XSS injection to all data etc)..

Answer (score 0):

At the start of your button you assign the value to the variable array

```
array = $(this).attr('data-qry');
```

But you send qry with the ajax

```
data    : 'qry='+qry,
```

The way you fix this is by sending the variable you assign the value to